# Differential graded category. Prove $d \circ d = 0$

Tags: category-theory, homology-cohomology

I'm a beginner in category theory and due to my master-thesis I work with differential graded categories. I consider a category of functors between two finite rank module categories. where I'm defining a morphism of degree $n$ between two functors as:

Let $n \in \mathbb{N} $ and $M_{n+1} \xleftarrow{f_n} M_n \xleftarrow{f_{n-1}}M_{n-1} ... \xleftarrow{f_1} M_1$ any sequence of n module-homomorphisms. We call  $\phi^{(n)}_{UV} \in Hom_n(U,V)$ a morphism of degree $n$ between the functors $U$ and $V$, when it maps any sequence of n module-homomorphisms to a morphism from $U(M_1)$ to $V(M_{n+1})$ which is $\mathbb{C}$-linear in each morphism entry $f_i$ with $0 \leq i \leq n$. Where $Hom_n(U,V)$ denote the set of all morphisms of degree $n$ between $U$ and $V$. Thus we can write:
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\phi^{(n)}_{UV} : &\left( M_{n+1} \xleftarrow{f_n} M_n \xleftarrow{f_{n-1}}M_{n-1} ... \xleftarrow{f_1} M_1 \right) \\
& \to \phi^{(n)}_{UV}  \left( M_{n+1} \xleftarrow{f_n} M_n \xleftarrow{f_{n-1}}M_{n-1} ... \xleftarrow{f_1} M_1 \right) \in Hom(U(M_1),V(M_{n+1})).
\end{split} 
\end{align}

Then I define a differntial in the following way:

For two functors $U,V \in Fun_{R,R'}$the differential of morphism a $\phi^{(n)}_{UV}$ maps it to a morphisms of degree $n+1$ which is defined by

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\left( d \phi^{(n)}_{UV} \right) & \left( M_{n+2} \xleftarrow{f_{n+1}} M_{n+1} \xleftarrow{f_{n-1}}M_{n} ... \xleftarrow{f_1} M_1 \right) \\ &= V(f_{n+1}) \circ  \phi^{(n)}_{UV}  \left( M_{n+1} \xleftarrow{f_n} M_n \xleftarrow{f_{n-1}}M_{n-1} ... \xleftarrow{f_1} M_1 \right) \\
&+ (-1) \phi^{(n)}_{UV}  \left( M_{n+2} \xleftarrow{f_{n+1} \circ f_n} M_{n} \xleftarrow{f_{n-1}}M_{n-1} ... \xleftarrow{f_1} M_1 \right) \\
&+... \\
&+ (-1)^n \phi^{(n)}_{UV}  \left( M_{n+2} \xleftarrow{f_{n+1}} M_{n+1} \xleftarrow{f_{n-1}}M_{n} ... \xleftarrow{f_2 \circ f_1} M_1 \right)\\
&+ (-1)^{n+1} \phi^{(n)}_{UV}  \left( M_{n+2} \xleftarrow{f_{n+1}} M_{n+1} \xleftarrow{f_{n-1}}M_{n} ... \xleftarrow{f_2} M_2 \right) \circ U(f_1)
\end{split}
\end{align}

Now I want to prove that $d \circ d=0$ and my question is if there is a kind of standard argument that $d \circ d=0$ since the differential looks very similar to other differentials where we know that $d \circ d = 0$. Or I painfully had to calculate this? Eventually, there is some other way to prove this?

Comment: In a way, it boils down to calculation, but the biig cancellation is close to obvious: You start with $M_{n+2}\leftarrow\ldots\leftarrow M_1$ and applying $d$ twice. This will result in a sum (linearity!) of expressions involving sequences with precisely two terms $M_i,M_j$ dropped (or composed away if you prefer). If you drop first $M_i$, then $N_j$, or if you drop $M_j$ first and then $M_i$, will produce opposite signs, hence these summands cancel. The only caes to be careful are $(i,j)=(1,2)$ and $(i,j)=(n+1,n+2)$, but there $U(f_2)\circ U(f_1)=U(f_2\circ f_1)$ etc. comes to the resue

Comment: The only thing I didn't understand completely how the terms including  $V(f_{n+2} ) \circ V(f_{n+1})$ and the terms $U(f_{2}) \circ U(f_1)$ should cancel out? Or how the differential act on those?

Answer (score 1):

The standard argument is a simplicial one. I will denote a composable tuple of morphisms by $f = (f_n,\ldots,f_0)$ and will write $\varphi$ for a map that takes such a tuple and assigns it to a map $U(s(f_0))\to V(t(f_n))$. Your differential then breaks up into the following coface maps:

1. Delete and act on the left: $d_0(\phi)(f) = V(f_n)\circ \phi(f_{n-1},\ldots,f_0)$,
2. Compose in the middle: $d_i(\phi)(f) = \phi(f_n,\ldots,f_{i+1}f_i,\ldots,f_0)$ where $i=0,\ldots,n-1$,
3. Delte and act on the right: $d_n(\phi)(f) = \phi(f_n,\ldots,f_1)\circ U(f_0)$.

Now show these maps satisfy the [cosimplicial identities](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simplicial+identities), which shows their alternating sum, as you have defined it, gives your a differential.